# Need help with raydium sdk

Tags: spl-token, raydium, sdk

I am building a swap like app that uses raydium but I'm facing alot of problems.

I copied someone's code and tried to change it a little bit but something is quite off.

Whenever I try to sell the whole amount of token inside my token account - it sells only a portion of it. it sometimes sells 10% and other times 99% but never 100% as I try to.

I'm not really sure how to use the Raydium sdk and there is no where to read or learn about it really besides reading the code in github which I already tried, Please help.

code:

```
async calcAmountOut(poolKeys: LiquidityPoolKeys, rawAmountIn: number, swapInDirection: boolean) {
    const poolInfo = await Liquidity.fetchInfo({ connection, poolKeys });

    let currencyInMint = poolKeys.baseMint;
    let currencyInDecimals = poolInfo.baseDecimals;
    let currencyOutMint = poolKeys.quoteMint;
    let currencyOutDecimals = poolInfo.quoteDecimals;

    if (!swapInDirection) {
        currencyInMint = poolKeys.quoteMint;
        currencyInDecimals = poolInfo.quoteDecimals;
        currencyOutMint = poolKeys.baseMint;
        currencyOutDecimals = poolInfo.baseDecimals;
    }

    const currencyIn = new Token(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, currencyInMint, currencyInDecimals);
    const amountIn = new TokenAmount(currencyIn, rawAmountIn, false);
    const currencyOut = new Token(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, currencyOutMint, currencyOutDecimals);
    const slippage = new Percent(0, 100); // 5% slippage

    const { amountOut, minAmountOut, currentPrice, executionPrice, priceImpact, fee } = Liquidity.computeAmountOut({
        poolKeys,
        poolInfo,
        amountIn,
        currencyOut,
        slippage,
    });

    return {
        amountIn,
        amountOut,
        minAmountOut,
        currentPrice,
        executionPrice,
        priceImpact,
        fee,
    };
}



async getOwnerTokenAccounts(keypair: Keypair): Promise<TokenAccount[]> {
    return (
        await connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(keypair.publicKey, {
            programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        })
    ).value.map(i => ({
        pubkey: i.pubkey,
        programId: i.account.owner,
        accountInfo: SPL_ACCOUNT_LAYOUT.decode(i.account.data),
    }));
}



async getSwapTransaction(
    keypair: Keypair,
    toToken: string,
    amount: number,
    poolKeys: LiquidityPoolKeys,
    fixedSide: 'in' | 'out' = 'in',
): Promise<VersionedTransaction> {
    const directionIn: boolean = poolKeys.quoteMint.toString() == toToken;
    const { minAmountOut, amountIn } = await this.calcAmountOut(poolKeys, amount, directionIn);

    const userTokenAccounts = await this.getOwnerTokenAccounts(keypair);
    const swapTransaction = await Liquidity.makeSwapInstructionSimple({
        connection,
        makeTxVersion: TxVersion.V0,
        poolKeys,
        userKeys: {
            tokenAccounts: userTokenAccounts,
            owner: keypair.publicKey,
        },
        amountIn,
        amountOut: minAmountOut,
        fixedSide,
        config: {
            bypassAssociatedCheck: false,
        },
    });

    const recentBlockhashForSwap = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    const instructions = swapTransaction.innerTransactions[0].instructions.filter(Boolean);

    const versionedTransaction = new VersionedTransaction(
        new TransactionMessage({
            payerKey: keypair.publicKey,
            recentBlockhash: recentBlockhashForSwap.blockhash,
            instructions: instructions,
        }).compileToV0Message(),
    );

    versionedTransaction.sign([keypair]);

    return versionedTransaction;
}



async sendVersionedTransaction(tx: VersionedTransaction) {
    return await connection.sendTransaction(tx, {
        skipPreflight: true,
        maxRetries: 2,
    });
}
```

Comment: It's a bit tough to get Raydium support in the Solana Stack Exchange unfortunately, so be sure to reach out to any other server or help that you can.